# How to create durable queue consumer using ActiveMq and C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, activemq-classic, messaging

I am new to activemq and trying to use it as a messaging service in C#.net application.
I was able to create Publisher/Subscriber for durable topics. But for my application requirement I need  to use Durable queue's. I don't see any create consumer method available for durable queue in Apache.NMS api. So, how can I create pub/sub using durable queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queue's are durable by nature.  You don't have to do anything special for a consumer when subscribing to a Queue, messages sent to the Queue that are marked as Persistent will survive a broker restart and remain on the Queue.  Your Queue subscription will pull messages off in order and they will only be removed from the Queue when you Ack them.